# Generate Firebase Registration token for a different Firebase project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have an app connected to default Firebase project. For Notifications, we use a Legacy (secondary) Firebase project.

I have figured out how to connect to secondary Firebase server, Auth to read from Database.

For push notifications, currently, I am using the default Firebase project generated token. But now, I am trying to see if I can generate a registration token for the secondary Firebase project so I can use the Legacy project for Push notifications.

Since `FirebaseInstanceIdService` is where the tokens are generated, I feel it's tied to the default Firebase service which is read from services JSON file. I still would like to keep the default JSON service file since a lot of APIs are connected using the default Firebase account.

Any idea to use the secondary Firebase project to generate token?

Answer (score 2):

Just call [`getToken(String, String)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#getToken(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), passing the Sender ID of your Secondary Project. Like so:

```
getToken("2xxxxx3344", "FCM");
```

It will return a (different) Registration token that corresponds to the secondary project, where you can now send push notifications from.

Do keep in mind that `getToken(String, String)` is a blocking function so do not call it on the main thread.

Similar posts (possibly duplicate):

- [How to put multiple project_number/sender id in google-services.json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37974658/4625829)
- [Receive push notifications on one android app from two Firebase projects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42117592/4625829)

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of the Firebase SDK, this is done using different way.

A detailed guide is explained in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65863769/1161911).