# Subscribe to Topic from Two Different Firebase Projects

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an Android Library project `com.random.lib`, and an Android Application project `com.random.app`.
`com.random.app` is using Library `com.random.lib`.
I've installed `com.random.app` on my phone.

The Library `com.random.lib` is registered in Firebase Project `FireLib`, while Application `com.random.app` also has its own Firebase Project `FireApp`.

The `com.random.lib` is subscribing to `awesome` topic in `FireLib`.

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("awesome");
```

The `com.random.app` is subscribing to `random` topic in `FireApp`.

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("random");
```

However, when I try to push a message to `awesome` topic from `FireLib` console, my phone didn't receive the push. When I push a new message to `random` topic from `FireApp` console, my phone received the push successfully.

Q: How to receive push message from `awesome` topic if a message is sent from `FireLib`?

I've bumped into [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42118836/4447757) and I've tried to send a push message directly to a single device using FCM registration token and it works (My phone did receive both push messages from both Firebase projects). However it's not what I want since I need to target the receiver based on the topic.

Comment: I haven't tried implementing it before, but in the scenario you provided, there are two different projects, in order to send a message coming from a different project than the app is associated to. You'll have to grant permission (see my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42118836/4625829)) to the FireLib project in order for the device to receive any messages from it. Not sure how you'll do it via the library though.

Comment: I do this as workaround: the `com.random.app` needs to generate 2 different tokens (`FireLib` and `FireApp` token), then subscribe each token to preferred topic from associated project using this [link](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#create_a_relation_mapping_for_an_app_instance).
But I still haven't find a way to do it directly from the Android library though.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong, this should not be possible. The main package name is `com.random.app`, as the library doesn't override it. The app will be published under the app's package name, hence it gets notifications for its package name only.

In the case your app would have the package name `com.random.lib` it could listen for the notifications.