# How to send notification between two application

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, android-notifications

I want to send push notification from Device "A" with Application "A" to Device "B" with application "B" how I can achieve that?

Any help will be appreciated.

can I use `firebase` with that?

With parse I can define that with number like :

```
ParseQuery query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
query.whereEqualTo("phone", "1234567890");
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setQuery(query);
push.sendPushInBackground();
```

how can I achieve that in other cases ?

Comment: See [This article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably have to go with something like this:

1. Create two separate Firebase Projects for each app with FCM enabled. (Project A and B)
2. Implement FCM for both Apps and generate tokens for each project to both apps (i.e. App A has tokenA and tokenB, App B has tokenC and tokenD). See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42118836/4625829).
3. Store the tokens to the corresponding servers.

From there, the flow of interaction should be something like:

```
App A > sends data > Server A // (contains App B's tokenC)
Server A > sends notification > App B // (by using tokenC)
```

and vice versa:

```
App B > sends data > Server B // (contains App A's tokenB)
Server B > sends notification > App A // (by using tokenB)
```

That's pretty much the general idea.

<sub>With all that said, "*how can I achieve that in other cases?*" is *too broad* of a question.</sub>

Comment: I have did the same procedure BUT I did not get the notification

Answer (score 0):

No, because package name will be different for two application. You cannot use same google-services.json file in both application if you are using FCM.

Comment: then how **uber** or **booking** used it ?

Comment: both app had different package name but  belong to same company so does.

Comment: @CODE1010101010101 we can use other servers for send push if server has deviceToken and it is using same FCM server key.

Answer (score 0):

**First of all Parse no more exists**

now coming to your question yes you can send the push from application A to application B

First implement FCM in App B and store the device id on server.

Now you have device id of App B  with user id on server.

Now send request to server to send the push from A to B.