# Sending push notification from different servers

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

We have an app. App can register to **different servers**: Server1 and Server2.

Now, Server1 and Server2 wants to send push notifications to an app **independently**. How to solve it using GCM?

I don't know how to implement in the sense of `SenderID`, `registration token`. Can an app has **one** `SenderID` for every app server? Should I has a one SenderID and generates different registration token for every app server?

Answer (score 0):

> *Now, Server1 and Server2 wants to send push notifications to an app independently. How to solve it using GCM?*

Have each server create their own FCM project (it seems you're a new user so it would be advisable to proceed using FCM now), each would have it's own SenderId, which the client would be generating a token for each (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42118836/4625829) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37981412/4625829)).

Then have the servers send to their corresponding tokens as needed.

> *Can an app has one SenderID for every app server?*

Yup. See what I mentioned above.

> *Should I has a one SenderID and generates different registration token for every app server?*

Yup. It's the correct approach, see what mentioned above.