# onNewToken() triggers twice for multiple sender IDs

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We're actively developing a push notification SDK and migrating it to FCM system since GCM is deprecated.

SDK gradle file includes the **firebase-messaging** package and SDK handles all the token registration and message received actions correctly. SDK gets the token from `instanceId.getToken(senderid, "fcm")` method and sends it to the cloud side successfully.

The problem occurs *while testing the multiple sender id* cases. If customer uses its own Firebase implementation(17.1.0+) with default sender id (getting from google-services.json), onNewToken method will trigger twice for both SDK and customer sender IDs interestingly. We expect to get only customer sender id (default one).

How can we understand where token comes from ? from which sender id ?

(We also contacted with Google, but they are unable to help)

Answer (score 1):

The practice I usually go for is to call `getToken(senderid, scope)` per each sender as needed. This way, you're sure to get the expected token.

However, if the goal is to get the default one, then there's no need to worry. [`onNewToken()` will only return the token for the default sender](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52676833/4625829).

Comment: Thanks for answer. We expect it to return only default sender id's token too, but as per my question, it returns two tokens in onNewToken(), instead of one. But we need one token for each sender as you mentioned. Anyway, we are checking out if our implementation is causing this unexpected behavior, thanks again.

Comment: `onNewToken()` returns a single string. That string is the default one. Like I mentioned above, if multiple senders are implemented, you should call `getToken(senderId, scope)` inside `onNewToken()`. That way, you won't be confused which the token is from which sender.

Comment: Actually by that I tried to mean `onNewToken()` executed twice.

Comment: That is odd.. I assume it's also returning two different tokens? Or is it the same?

Comment: What did the Google Official support say about this? Either way, the workaround I mentioned above could still work. Just make sure to supply the senderId as needed and it should be fine.

Comment: They said what you said :) I will investigate again, thanks!