# About send notification to other app through FCM

Tags: android, ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to send notification from app A to other apps through cloud messaging server?
For example. I have an **app A** and **app B** in same project. And I have an **app C** in other project.
Of course in **app A server side** I can send notification to **app A client** through FCM server.
Is it possible in **app A server side**, that I can send notification to **app B client** or **app C client** through FCM server by using FCM API?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see a problem here , all you need is API key of the project and device token to send a notification ,

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. The ability to send to a project depends on having a valid sender ID for that project. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42117592/receive-push-notifications-on-one-android-app-from-two-firebase-projects and the documentation linked from there.