# How to specify sender ID in FCM?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

[Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) says:

> When a client app registers for FCM, it must specify which senders are allowed to send messages.

So, how can an app specify which senders it allows to send messages?

Comment: Older FCM SDKs used to have a `getToken()` function where you could specify the senderId (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42118836/4625829) for a few details), but the recent versions (using `FirebaseMessaging`), doesn't seem to have one. I haven't dabbled with FCM for a while, but my guess is that they put it somewhere in the initialization part of FirebaseMessaging. Might need to check if you could pass a FirebaseApp instance somewhere.

Comment: @AL. I get it but even if you don't specify the sender, you can still see the notifications, can't you. So, why the docs are saying, *... it must specify ...*