# How do I access Firebase tokens outside of the FirebaseInstanceIdService?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm upgrading from GCM to FCM. What is the proper way to obtain a Firebase device token outside of onTokenRefresh?

I'm trying to get the device token so that I can re-enable it on my server at a later time. I initially get device token by following the documentation shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) for Method 1. However when I attempt to access the device token directly via method 2 I get a different token. Am I retrieving the device token incorrectly in method 2?

Method 1: inside of FirebaseInstanceIdService.onTokenRefresh()

```
String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

Method 2: Direct access to the device token

```
FirebaseInstanceId instanceID = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance();
String registrationToken = instanceID.getToken(this.projectNumber, "FCM");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to explain what is happening in *Method 1*. It is suggested to get the token inside [`onTokenRefresh()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService.html#onTokenRefresh()) since when this method is triggered, it means that the *previous* token got invalidated. From the docs:

> Called when the system determines that the tokens need to be refreshed. The application should call getToken() and send the tokens to all application servers.

For *Method #2*, you're calling [`getToken(String authorizedEntity, String scope)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#getToken(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), instead of [`getToken()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#getToken()). The one with two parameters is commonly used when [setting up your app to receive messages from multiple senders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37981412/4625829).

For each call to `getToken(String authorizedEntity, String scope)` with a different project ID (`authorizedEntity`) it will return a different token.

Just replace your *Method 2* with the same call in *Method 1*, like so:

```
String registrationToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

and you should be able to retrieve the designated token. The token is often retrieved in the `onCreate()` of your initial activity.

Comment: Got it. Do you happen to know why is it that Method #2 returning a different token if I am using the same projectID as what is specified in the google-services.json? I would assume that they ought to be the same if they use the same ID.

Comment: Nothing is stated in the docs on how it works internally. What I do think that happens is, since the `getToken(String, String)` is expected to only be used for registering different senders, it automatically treats the Sender ID (regardless if it is the default/or the one google-services.json) as a different one. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a finer solution to this question, this is how I would approach it. A unique token will be generated if your application runs for the first time or you just cleared application data.

To access `token` outside of the `FirebaseInstanceIdService` class, use the SharedPreference inside `onTokenRefresh` and save your token as shown below.

```
public class FireBaseTokenClass extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();


        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("file_save_token", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("myToken", refreshedToken);
        editor.apply();


    }
}
```

To access your token outside the service class, just say this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("file_save_token", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
    String token = sharedPreferences.getString("myToken", "");
```