# Will Firebase sender/server key change effect currently subscribed topics?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

We need to move an app from an existing project in Firebase to a new project with a different sender/server key.  Will topic subscriptions still work for past users?  I am assuming they aren't tied to the sender/server key of the project but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would change. The registration token that is used to subscribe to a topic is tied to the senderId (project) that it is created from -- it's why enabling multiple senders would create different tokens per sender.

So yes. If you're going to move, you'll have to somehow subscribe all the users to their corresponding topics on that new project.

Comment: Wow, Google is making us move all our 400 apps under one project to single projects.

Comment: There doesnt seem to be a way to reassign current topic users to new ones, since they dont provide an api to do so

Comment: If you move the users to a new project, you'd have to go through the registration process to each of them again. Using the resulting tokens, you could use the InstanceId server API to batchAdd the users to a topic.

Comment: I was doing that, but it seems the tokens are tied to the firebase project key, so I cant reuse the tokens to reassign topics under this new key.

Comment: I would suggest [enabling multiple senders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37981412/4625829) to the app to get a token for your new project, save the corresponding tokens, then do the batchAdd.

Comment: Yes I will have to, but that is over 400+ apps I would have to resubmit code for.  Quite ridiculous if you ask me.