# Token update in FCM

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM in my project and my application is register with two FCM project (two sender ID).

Now i want to handle token refresh.And as per document i will get below call back

```
@Override
public void onNewToken(String token) {
   Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);
}
```

but have may i know which token is updated ?
token updated for sender_id_1 or token updated for sender_id_2 ?

Question 2 : If i receive onNewToken call back with newToken value and if i do not pass that value to server and server try to send push on older token, then what will happen ? what error i will received from FCM ?

Thanks

Comment: how do you register two FCM sender ids?

Comment: @peshkira See my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37974658/4625829)

Comment: @peshkira the answer you are said is for how to register with multiple send.But my question is how to do handle token refresh for multiple sender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Looking at the docs for [`onNewToken()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService.html#onNewToken(java.lang.String)) (emphasis mine):

> Called when a new token for the **default Firebase project** is generated.
>
> This is invoked after app install when a token is first generated, and again if the token changes.

Default project points to the first project.

2. Sending to an expired token would result to a [`NotRegistered`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) error

Comment: Thank you for answer, I am also thing the same.That i will not get token update for both the sender, i will get for default project only.This is big gap in FCM design from firebase right ?