# Migrating GCM tokens to another account

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are trying to migrate push notifications from GCM to Firebase.
We don't know the account in which app is registered. Because it was developed by a company which has closed.
We only have the `API_KEY`, so we can't log in the account to migrate GCM to FCM.

We are trying to create a new account which Firebase enabled, but we need to migrate the tokens to he new account (we have tokens stored in database to send push notifications).

Do you know if it is possible?

---

We have asked to Google Support, and they told us the google account. But we can't login because we don't know the password, and we couldn't recover it.. :(

I don't understand the opcion 2. 
We have created a new account with Firebase, and we will migrate app to the new account. 
Users that update app, will generate new Firebase tokens in new account.
But user who don't update, in Aprill will stop receive push notifications, since GCM account will not work anymore...
How option 2 can help in this scenario?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to migrate GCM (or FCM) tokens from a different project to a different one.

There are 2 possible options I could think of that you could go for:

1. Reach out to Official Google Support, maybe they could help you recover the corresponding project, find the developer that owns it, and transfer the ownership (if possible) to you.
2. Implement [multiple senders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37974658/4625829) on a newer version of your app to start generating tokens that allows your new project to send messages to the users.