# Given a FCM sender id, can any one send msg to our server?

Tags: firebase

In our use case, we need to use multiple sender id to send msg to server. According to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37974658/how-to-put-multiple-project-number-sender-id-in-google-services-json), I successfully send msg to our server using multiple sender id.

What confuse me is that if I can send msg to the server only given a sender id, any others with the sender id can send msg to our server too. Does it harm?

Test env: sender id A configured in google-service.json, sender id B used to send msg to server and it works.

Comment: could any one tells me why this is not a good question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From FCM support:

> After discussing with our engineers, it seems that FCM doesn't have an authorization mechanism for upstream messages. We will be working on a fix for this, although we can't share any timelines for now as to when the fix with be available. You may keep an eye out on our [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases) for further updates.

It **is** a bug of firebase

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know that's not possible to send FCM message only with sender id. You need to send your server key in the HTTP POST request header as a Authorization  key. According to this link a sample FCM POST request is as follows.

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{ 
   "data": {
      "score": "5x1",
      "time": "15:10"
},
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
}
```

If anyone has the server key than they can send FCM to your sever

Comment: I use the java api and the only param specified is sender id (say, send msg to sender_id@gcm.googleapis.com)